# Simulate transitions between states in R

Tags: r, simulation, markov

So I have got a data table containing about 100 rows of data, each row representing a different person. And for each person, their transition probabilities to four different states are listed in columns.
I've got a
snippet of the table.

[image]

What is the best way for me to simulate their transitions within the next period in R? Is the Markov chain approach the best available?

Comment: *"What is the best way for me to simulate their transitions"* - this sounds to me as if the question is primarily opinion based. Maybe you could rephrase the question, list what drawbacks you see in a Markov Chain and why you don't want to use it, list your requirements and ask, if someone knows an algorithm that will fulfil your requirements better.

Comment: how fine-grained do you want/need your simulation to be?  Are you tracking states for each person individually? Do the `age` and `gender` variables matter?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do, hence it isn't very clear how to answer your question. Also: please don't give an *image* of the data -- give the data itself in a way that others can load it into an R console.